# Renaming multiple file names (removing the ending of file names)

Tags: unix

I would like to rename these files to not have the ending of (.processed2011*)

So, basically, rename

self_reported_user_activity_1404414367_131826464204632784.csv.processed20111011014111557
self_reported_user_activity_1404539338_131826361077732732.csv.processed20111011021401718
self_reported_user_activity_1404418376_131826222854532675.csv.processed20111011014301356
self_reported_user_activity_1404539858_131826370284032733.csv.processed20111011021431708

to

self_reported_user_activity_1404414367_131826464204632784.csv 
self_reported_user_activity_1404539338_131826361077732732.csv
self_reported_user_activity_1404418376_131826222854532675.csv 
self_reported_user_activity_1404539858_131826370284032733.csv

---

My 'rename' command is the following (without regex):

NAME
       rename - Rename files
SYNOPSIS
       rename from to file...

Thanks

Comment: http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/01/bulk-renaming-of-files-in-unix.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try using the "cut" command.  Something like this:

```
for f in *
do
  g=`cut -d"." -f2`
  mv $f $g
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `${string%substring}` which deletes the longest match of `substring` from the back of the string. So if `line` contains a `self_...`:

```
newline=${line%.*}
```